# how to compress file.json with php and decompress with javascript?

Tags: json, compression

I have over 10,000 records in mysql db (items table) 
by querying at items table , json (over 3 mb) file generated  by php on the server.
I need to decompres (client side) and then read json to use on google map markers.

I need to know best way to compress json file on server side with php and decompress at client side with javascripts , ajax or jquery.

Comment: Can't you just use GZip compression which is built into the web server?

Comment: yes I did.
$file = "test.txt";
$gzfile = "test.gz";
$fp = gzopen ($gzfile, 'w9');
gzwrite ($fp, file_get_contents($file));
gzclose($fp);     and it works. I have a file with 30 kb size. I need to extract or decompress the gz file in client side

Comment: You missed the point of what I said. Let the webserver do the compression for you. For example, IIS will GZip content for you if you let it, you will not need to write any code.

Comment: my problem is transfering large file from server to clients. I need to search on json file content in client side for showing markers on the map. will webserver help me for this issue ??

Comment: You mean I need to use deflate mod on apache server ? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html  this solution allows output from your server to be compressed before being sent to the client over the network but I dont have access or permission for changing apache servers config. also I dont want to compress all supported types ! I need to work only with json file

Comment: Possibly, I don't use Apache much. I'd be surprised it it wasn't already turned on, it's useful for all content on your sites.

Comment: My hosting provider is godady.and I think this feature is off.

Comment: do you have any idea to decompress gzip files on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Use mode_deflate which is part of Apache. You say your provider is GoDaddy, here is the link on how to enable the feature:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6946/enabling-mod_deflate-with-your-hosting-account